# Who was the first to estimate the vacuum energy discrepancy by 120 orders of magnitude?

Tags: physics, cosmology

Apparently, this discrepancy is one of the "worst predictions" in the history of science. Clearly the vacuum energy calculation depends on many approximations and it is not clear how it should be tied to the cosmological constant. Some articles claim that the two differ by 120 orders of magnitude, however it is not clear for me who was the first to publish this number or where it comes from. I have checked reviews like:

- [Everything you always wanted to know about the cosmological constant problem 2012](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.crhy.2012.04.008) but the author just says: ''122 orders of magnitude often quoted in the literature'' no ref.
- [Weinberg (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.61.1) does not offer much better, he cites [Abbott 1988 popular science article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-mystery-of-the-cosmological-con/), but Abbott only refers to the 45 orders of magnitude.
- [Zeldovich 1968](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10714-008-0624-6) the magnitude is 42(?) no mention of 120 or 122
- The value has to predate 1984, because Alan Guth was referring already to it in his *The New Inflationary Universe* (1983) lecture, see also  [Hawking (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1983.0092) .
- W. Nernst, W. Lenz and W. Pauli seem to have discussed the problem long before Zeldovich (in the 1920s) mostly in German. Maybe one of them?

So who was the first to publish such a large difference of 120 or 122? Did the author specify values for both the vacuum energy calculation and measurements of the cosmological constant?

Comment: The discrepancy is between the values found from gravity/cosmology and QFT. As far as I know, the first to become aware of this was Pauli, see e.g. [this lecture](https://indico.cern.ch/event/425387/attachments/903020/1273882/lect.5.pdf) by Straumann.

Comment: Another early work is by Zeldovich (1968), entitled "The cosmological constant and the theory of elementary particles". It has been [republished](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10714-008-0624-6) as a "Golden Oldie" in 2008. Pauli's contribution is mentioned by the historical editor of the republication as their first reference.

Comment: @TomHeinzl I am not looking for the beginning of the discrepancy I am looking the original 120 orders value, I could not find it in your link

Comment: The measured value of the cosmological constant is roughly $\Lambda \approx 10^{-44} \mbox{GeV}^4$. In QFT, it is given by a divergent integral that has to be cut off, typically at some mass value, $M$, yielding the estimate $\Lambda \sim M^4$. Pauli chose the mass associated with the classical electron radius, implying $\Lambda \sim 10^{-5} \mbox{GeV}^4$ (off by 39 orders of magnitude). Choosing $M$ to be the Planck mass ($10^{19}$ GeV), one finds the 120 orders of magnitude discrepancy,  $\Lambda \sim 10^{76} \mbox{GeV}^4$. So your question is: who first used the Planck mass as a cutoff?

Comment: @TomHeinzl yes, who was the first to set that cutoff

Comment: @njuffa the Chandra paper does not seems to be indexed in journal finders, do you know if it had some influence on the others?

Comment: @njuffa who is the author of the New Scientist article? Do they cite somebody for the 120 orders?

Comment: @njuffa New Scientist article by Matthew is not right as it is Number 1966/1965 but it was published in 1995

Comment: @njuffa from time to time for specific bits of information I've emailed directly to the reference librarians of various libraries around the world, and invariably they have taken some time to access various things and share electronic copies with me. It's not a way to research a topic, but very often you can get copies of hard-to-find things that way. You may also consider searching a database of Masters and Ph.D. theses on the topic of vacuum energy and its predictions by narrowing your search to text of theses. Most universities make them accessible. It's slow and painstaking, but sometimes

Comment: @njuffa there are real gems. I wrote mine on an exotic isotope and I included an obscure image of the decay tracks of the first ever atom of the isotope ever produced, just because it was the one time in my life when I could really dig into the history. It's possible somewhere some student dug deep into this vacuum energy history as well. Searching theses is not always quick but it may hit pay dirt.